# How to set custom endpoint Uri via Bing Speech-to-Text *Android* SDK?

Tags: android, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I'm testing custom speech service with Bing Speech-to-Text Android SDK.

However, I cannot set my custom endpoint's Uri with Android SDK.
In current SDK, endpoint Uri is hardcoded in SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.class of aar library, and there are no way to change it.
(In windows SDK, we can easily change it.)

Please tell me how to set custom endpoint Uri on Android Bing speech SDK?

Best Regards;

Answer (score 0):

Solved :-)

The library has deprecated entry that enables custom endpoint. For example:

Original (with std endpoint):

```
                    this.micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClient(
                        this,
                        this.getMode(),
                        this.getDefaultLocale(),
                        this,
                        this.getPrimaryKey());
```

Changed (with custom endpoint):

```
                    this.micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClient(
                        this,
                        this.getMode(),
                        this.getDefaultLocale(),
                        this,
                        this.getPrimaryKey(),
                        this.getPrimaryKey(),
                        "YourCustomEndPoint");
```

---

Happy Hacking!